# React Native(Android) Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, github-api, expo

I'm trying to send post request to google api for text detection. But first i must take a picture then i can send this picture google api with axios.

The following codes are for taking pictures.

```
takePictureAndCreateAlbum = async () => {
    let uri = this.camera.takePictureAsync({
      base64: true
    }).then(data => {
        this.sendVisionOCR(data)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("err", err)}
      )
   const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
   console.log('asset', asset);
   MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Expo', asset)
     .then(() => {
       Alert.alert('Album created!')
     })
     .catch(error => {
       Alert.alert('An Error Occurred!')
     });
    };
}
```

And the following codes are for send request a goole api.

```
sendVisionOCR(data){
      let body = {
        "requests":[
          {
            "image":{
              "content": data
            },
            "features": [
                  {
                    "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION",
                    "maxResults": 1
                  }
                ]
          }
        ]
      }
axios.post('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=xxXXxx', body)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("worked", response)

      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("err", err))
}
```

When i run my code, I got these error;

**Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):**

Error: Invalid argument "localUri". It must be a string!

But sometimes if I change my code a small part, I saw infinite loop. It's trying to send base64 file.

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"expo": "^31.0.2",
"react": "16.5.0",
```

And I also tried to fetch operation. It's not working?

What is a problem? Why axios is not working?

Comment: The problem localUri is unrelated to the Axios "not working" the asset you are passing is an incorrect URI, is why you get localUri error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Actually my code is working corretly. There is a another problem. When I running the code it takes a very long time to encode picture base64 format and only seems to work sometimes. There is [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899703/takepictureasync-base64-encoding-performing-slowly) question.

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please provide an adequate answer or place this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting same issue then after made changes on plugin code and it's works.
inside expo-local-authentication have one file : LocalAuthentication.js made below changes on that file.

```
const result = await ExpoLocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync({ ...options, promptMessage });
```

replace with

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
let result=undefined ; 
if(Platform.OS == 'ios'){
    result = await ExpoLocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync({ ...options, promptMessage });  
}else{
    result = await ExpoLocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync();
}
```

thanks :)